QGIS unable to unzip file. Possible GPKG issue?
Having issues with QGIS 3.34 and 3.36 giving the error: Unable to Unzip File xxxxxx.qgz
Often times these qgis files were made by the same user that was trying to open them again. This issue has been reported by  multiple users  in our organization. Using qgis 3.34LTR and 3.36, multiple people are reporting they can't open their qgis project files. They get an error message saying qgis cannot unzip the file.
I have been able to open these files using 3.36 and save them as a .qgs file and it seems to save everything appropriately. But any ideas why they are getting this error??
Another thing - not sure if it's related, but our organization has recently switched to using gpkg instead of zip files. And I've been saving vector layer styles to the gpkg. I'm not sure if this could be partially responsible?
Update - for one qgz file with this issue, the only thing in the qgz file is a qgs file and a styles.db file which will be the styles that should be saved in the gpkg

is this on windows? with a shared drive?

For what it is worth... we have been using (many) .gpkg with sometimes embedded layer styles in combination with .qgz project files for many years (on windows shared/network drives) and never had an issue like this. At the moment we are on qgis version 3.34.3

As a workaround, if a user has this problem, he could try to rename the .qgz to .zip, unzip it, then open the unzipped .qgs file? But it is weird that it happens in the first place of course...

The qgis project and gis data are stored on Microsoft SharePoint locations. We have been operating like this for several years. The only change I can think of is the gpkg styles. We are on windows computers. Any advice on saving styles to gpkg? Could I be doijg something wrong?
